# Is there a way to change visibility of an item when switching app theme from styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to achieve an effect where this starry background animation is visible/gone depending on the selected app theme.

```
<com.starry.animation
        android:id="@+id/stars"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:starsView_bigStarThreshold="10dp"
        app:starsView_meteoritesColors="@array/meteorites_colors"
        app:starsView_meteoritesEnabled="true"
        app:starsView_meteoritesInterval="2000"
        app:starsView_maxStarSize="3dp"
        app:starsView_minStarSize="1dp"
        android:visibility="?visibilityMode"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:starsView_starColors="@array/star_colors_small"
        app:starsView_starCount="100" />
```

I've declared visibilityMode in styles.xml as string attribute

```
<attr name="visibilityMode" format="string" />
```

and in my custom theme as :

```
<item name="visibilityMode">GONE</item>
```

This results in an error inflating the stars view. Is there some other implementation I can achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually visibility is not a string but an integer.
`0` is used for visible initial state.
`2` is used for gone initial state
(don't be confused with `View.Gone` and `View.Visible`).

So in your case the custom attribute may look like:

```
<attr name="visibilityMode" format="integer">
  <!-- Visible on screen; the default value. -->
    <enum name="visible" value="0" />
    <!-- Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added. -->
    <enum name="gone" value="2" />
</atrr>
```

Than it can be used in theme:
`<item name="visibilityMode">gone</item>`

and in your layout item: `android:visibility="?visibilityMode"`

Please check out [this answer](http://check%20out%20this%20solution)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Only needed to change int to integer though, and close with </attr> instead

Comment: @TBoneEpclan great) i fixed an answer